# wordpress get_template_directory_uri function doesn't return template directory

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following function accessing a javascript file:

```
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/plugins.js"></script>
```

It should return:  http://example.com/mytemplate/js/plugins.js

Instead it returns:
http://example.com/_templates/default_site/js/placeholder.js

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: try ` echo get_bloginfo('template_url'); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
<script src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/js/plugins.js"></script>
```